# Not able to open IE browser.code and error both are in description?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class IEdrivercode 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       String driverpath = "path of IE Browser";
       System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",driverpath+"IEDriverServer.exe");
       WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();  
       System.out.println("Hello Google...");  
       driver.get("http://google.com"); 
       driver.close();
    }
}
```

Refer Image:

[image]

I have done all the settings from this [link](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-run-webdriver-in-ie-browser[enter).

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to uncheck "Enable protection mode" options to run Internet Explorer Browser through webdriver.

Follow this Steps:
Tools -> Internet options -> Security

Now **UNCHECK** "Enable protection mode" for all the 4 zones.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: didnt work . i am using windows 10 machine which has both Edge and IE Is this causing the problem.

Comment: No, it does not related with `edge` browser, See edge browser driver is totally different. `System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\Drivers\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
driver = new EdgeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://google.com");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

**Note:-** IE Driver should available, and IE driver path should be correct.

This can work out of the box without the `desired capability settings.`

Go to `internet options>>Security>>click on:'Reset all zones to default level and after that, ensure that the 'Enable protected mode' checkbox is ticked for all the four zones. Like i.e Internet , Local internet, Trusted Sites, Restricted Sites.`

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\Drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");                
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://google.com");
System.out.println("Hello Google");
driver.close();
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as `Accepted` if it's resolved your issue.